# How to use parametrized FirstOrDefault() method?

Tags: c#

Actually i came across with the usage of FirstOrDefault() in the following way.

```
var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
```

I am not able to make out what p is and how this works.

Comment: p is an element of `products` being iterated over. This is type inference. The compiler understand the type of `p` on its own without you having to explicitly state it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda expression inside the `FirstOrDefault` method applies to the collection that the method is used on.

In other words: when you use `xyz.FirstOrDefault()` or `xyz.FirstOrDefault(*lambda*)` then the FirstOrDefault applies to xyz. If there is a lambda, it further narrows down the options. So in the case

`xyz.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)`

this simply means that from the `xyz` collection, you take the first item where the `Id` of that item is equal to the `id` variable, OR you take `null` (the Default) in case there is none.

More simply stated: from the `xyz` collection, give me the first item where `Id == id`, or give me `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The construct

```
(p) => p.Id == id
```

Is a lambda function, also called an anonymous function. It takes one parameter, called `p`, of a type to be inferred by the compiler, and returns the value of the expression `p.Id == id`, taking `id` from the surrounding scope. `FirstOrDefault` executes it on each element in `products` in turn, passing each element as the parameter. The moment it returns true, `FirstOrDefault` will return that element from `products` and iterate no further through the collection. If no element causes a true result, it returns the default for the element type, which is `null` unless it's a value type.

Answer (score 0):

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) is an extension method. The signature of this particular overload is

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

This means that when `source` is `products` as in your call, `products` must be an `IEnumerable<TSource>` for some value of `TSource`. The compiler checks that this requirement is observed and knows that the second parameter `predicate` is a function that takes a `TSource` argument. That's what the type of `p` is.

The process by which the compiler determines what the type `TSource` is based on what arguments you call the method with is called [type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic10).